# Autocomplete with a Textbox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox

I am trying to add an autocomplete box to my winform.

The `GetDatabaseContent()` works fine when I apply it to a `combo box` but I want to add it to a `textbox`.

The issue my current code is that is brings the contents of my `Datatable` as a single line rather than a list.

Any help would be great.

```
Private Sub frmUser_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim mystring

    Dim dt As DataTable = GetDatabaseContent()
    mystring = FetchTable(dt)
    Dim newstr As New AutoCompleteStringCollection
    newstr.Add(mystring)
    txtbox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = newstr


End Sub

Function FetchTable(dt As DataTable)
    Dim mystring = ""
    For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
        mystring &= dr.Item(0).ToString
    Next
    Return mystring
End Function
```

Comment: I don't think normal TextBoxes don't have this behavior. Usually you use ComboBox. For the behavior you want you might need to find another control (or do some hacking to customize the ComboBox to not display the arrow button)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only creating a single line of text to use as the data source, so try just adding each row of text to the collection instead:

```
Dim newstr As New AutoCompleteStringCollection
For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
  newstr.Add(dr.Item(0).ToString)
Next
TextBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
TextBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
TextBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = newstr
```

Comment: lol - where were you 30 minutes ago? I figured out that I was missing a loop. You get lost when you have been staring at a code too long.